# I am trying to figure out how to parse a webpage

Tags: r, parsing, web-scraping

I am working on a summer project. To grab course information from my school website.

I start off by going here: http://www.uah.edu/cgi-bin/schedule.pl?file=fall2015.html&segment=
to gather the course departments.

Then I grab info from pages like this one. 
I have what I need filtered down to a list like:

```
 [1] "91091  211 01     PRINC OF FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING     3.0   55   22       33    0 MW      12:45PM 02:05PM BAB   106        Rose-Green E"
 [2] "91092  211 02     PRINC OF FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING     3.0   53   18       35    0 TR      09:35AM 10:55AM BAB   123        STAFF"       
 [3] "91093  211 03     PRINC OF FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING     3.0   48   29       19    0 TR      05:30PM 06:50PM BAB   220        Hoskins J"   
 [4] "91094  212 01     MANAGEMENT ACCOUNTING             3.0   55   33       22    0 MWF     11:30AM 12:25PM BAB   106        Hoskins J"   
 [5] "91095  212 02     MANAGEMENT ACCOUNTING             3.0   55   27       28    0 TR      02:20PM 03:40PM BAB   106        Bryson R"
```

However my issues are as follows:

[www.uah.edu/cgi-bin/schedule.pl?file=fall2015.html&segment=CS](http://www.uah.edu/cgi-bin/schedule.pl?file=fall2015.html&segment=CS)

I need to add the department from each url. In the link I gave, the department was "CS". I need to have that included with each entry.

I need to turn this into a table, or some other object where I can reference the data like

```
                                                              Max               Wait                                                                                                                    
     CRN    Course     Title                          Credit Enrl Enrl Avail    List Days    Start   End     Bldg  Room       Instructor                                                                
     ------ ---------- ------------------------------ ------ ---- ---- -------- ---- ------- ------- ------- ----- ---------- --------------------
```

Basically how the data is displayed on the page.

So my end goal is to go through each of those links I grab, get all the course info(except the section type). Then put it into a giant data.frame that has all the courses like this.

```
Department CRN    Course     Title                      Credit  MaxEnrl  Enrl Avail WaitList  Days    Start   End     Bldg  Room       Instructor   
ACC        91095  212 02     MANAGEMENT ACCOUNTING      3.0     55       27     28    0      TR      02:20PM 03:40PM   BAB   106        Bryson R
```

So far I have this working

```
require(data.table)
require(gdata)
library(foreach)

uah <- readLines('http://www.uah.edu/cgi-bin/schedule.pl?file=fall2015.html&segment=')
uah <- substring(uah[grep('fall2015', uah)], 10)
uah <- sub("\\\"(.*)", "", uah)
uah <- paste("http://www.uah.edu" , uah , sep = "")

gatherClasses <- function(url){

    dep <- readLines(url)

    dep <- dep[grep('[[:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]][[:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]] [[:digit:][:digit:]]', dep)]

    dep <- substring(dep, 6) 

    dep <- foreach(i=dep) %do% i[grep('[[:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]][[:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]] [[:digit:][:digit:]]', i)]

    dep <- foreach(i=dep) %do% trim(i)

    dep <- dep[2:length(dep)]

    return(dep)
}

x <- gatherClasses(uah[1])
x <-unlist(x)
```

I am having trouble split the data in the right places. I am not sure what I should try next.

EDIT:(Working Now)

```
require(data.table)
require(gdata)
library(foreach)

uah <- readLines('http://www.uah.edu/cgi-bin/schedule.pl?file=sum2015b.html&segment=')
uah <- substring(uah[grep('sum2015b', uah)], 10)
uah <- sub("\\\"(.*)", "", uah)
uah <- paste("http://www.uah.edu" , uah , sep = "")


gatherClasses <- function(url){

    L <- readLines(url)
    Fields <- sub(" *$", " ", grep("---", L, value = TRUE))
    widths <- diff(c(0, gregexpr(" ", Fields)[[1]]))
    Data <- grep("\\d{5}  \\d{3}", L, value = TRUE)
    classes <- read.fwf(textConnection(Data), widths, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
    classes$department <-  unlist(strsplit(url, '='))[3]

    return(classes)
}

allClasses = foreach(i=uah) %do% gatherClasses(i)
allClasses <- do.call("rbind", allClasses)

write.table(mydata, "c:/sum2015b.txt", sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the lines into `L`, grab the `"--- ---- etc."` line into Fields and ensure that there is exactly one space at the end.  Find the character positions of the spaces and difference them to get the field widths.  Finally `grep` out the data portion and read it in using `read.fwf` which reads fixed width fields.  For example, for Art History:

```
URL <- "http://www.uah.edu/cgi-bin/schedule.pl?file=fall2015.html&segment=ARH"
L <- readLines(URL)
Fields <- sub(" *$", " ", grep("---", L, value = TRUE))
widths <- diff(c(0, gregexpr(" ", Fields)[[1]]))
Data <- grep("\\d{5}  \\d{3} \\d{2}", L, value = TRUE)
read.fwf(textConnection(Data), widths, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
   V1    V2     V3                          V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10     V11     V12 V13 V14               V15
1     90628 100 01   ARH SURV:ANCIENT-MEDIEVAL  3 35 27  8  0  TR 12:45PM 02:05PM WIL 168           Joyce L
2     90630 101 01 ARH SURV:RENAISSANCE-MODERN  3 35 14 21  0  MW 12:45PM 02:05PM WIL 168         Stewart D
3     90631 101 02 ARH SURV:RENAISSANCE-MODERN  3 35  8 27  0  MW 03:55PM 05:15PM WIL 168         Stewart D
4     92269 101 03 ARH SURV:RENAISSANCE-MODERN  3 35  5 30  0  TR 11:10AM 12:30PM WIL 168 Shapiro Guanlao M
5     90632 101 04 ARH SURV:RENAISSANCE-MODERN  3 35 13 22  0  TR 02:20PM 03:40PM WIL 168 Shapiro Guanlao M
6     90633 301 01           ANCIENT GREEK ART  3 18  3 15  0  MW 02:20PM 03:40PM WIL 168           Joyce L
7     92266 306 01   COLLAPSE OF CIVILIZATIONS  3 10  4  6  0  TR 12:45PM 02:05PM SST 205           Sever T
8   W 90634 309 01   CONTEMPORARY ART & ISSUES  3 18 10  8  0  TR 09:35AM 10:55AM WIL 168         Stewart D
9     90635 320 01     ST: MODERN ARCHITECTURE  3 12  0 12  0  TR 11:10AM 12:30PM WIL 172          Takacs T
10    90636 400 01               SENIOR THESIS  3  0  0  0  0 TBA     TBA         TBA TBA           Joyce L
11    90637 400 02               SENIOR THESIS  3  0  0  0  0 TBA     TBA         TBA TBA         Stewart D
```

Comment: Using the dashes was very clever. I will try to remember that trick for the future. Also, thank you for making my regex better. I put my final-ish version up in my post in case anyone in the future needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote and donated that schedule.pl script about 20 years ago because they simply published the flat mainframe files of all the courses on offer for each session.  The script's job is to break up the whole set and present it in human-consumable chunks.  (That, and back then a browser would choke on that much data.) I understand from one of the former UAH IT people that they tried to do away with it once, but got a great hew and cry from users, so they figured out how to keep it working.

It would be easier for you to ask the UAH IT folks if you can't just retrieve the underlying flat file.  It used to be on a public-facing URL, but like I said, that was about 20 years ago, so I don't recall the specifics.  The output you see when viewing courses is the same as the flat file, but the flat file contains every department, so you don't have to fetch each separately.